# Skip building the ROS package when the .cpp file is not modified

Tags: ros, rosnode, ide

I'm using VS Code to debug the ROS node (i.e., `.cpp` file), here are part of my global launch.json and tasks.json files

launch.json:

```
    {
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug ROS Node",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/devel/lib/ROSPackage/ROSNode",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "preLaunchTask": "catkin build ROS Package"
    }
```

task.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "catkin build ROS Package",
            "type": "shell",
            "command":"catkin",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "-j16",
                "ROSPackage"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$catkin-gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

With the setting of `preLaunchTask`, every time I debug the ROS node I need to `catkin build` the package even if the `.cpp` file is not changed.

So my question is how to design an autodetection that can automatically skip the `catkin build` process if the `.cpp` file is not changed.

Is it possible through some settings in `.json` files?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! In my experience, `catkin` simply ignores and does not recompile if there is no change in the code. So, even if you execute `catkin` multiple times, it will skip the compilation process.

Comment: Hi! @ravi Thanks for the tip that `catkin` can implement this auto-detection process. For the sake of curiosity, is there any other way instead of using `catkin`?